# JSTL Removing nested conditionals

Tags: java, jstl

I'm pretty new to JSTL in general but thinking there has to be a better way to do this.
I have a nested JSTL conditional and it seems like a whole lot of code to basically output some text and a link. I was wondering if it's possible to set another variable with a conditional as the value and use that instead of having nested conditionals but I'm not entirely sure how to do that or if that's even the best approach. If there are any receommondations on how to make this more concise I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
<c:set var="footer" value="<%= new FooterComponent(resource) %>"/>

<c:choose>
<c:when test="${not empty footer.text}">
    <a target="${footer.target}">
    <c:choose>
       <c:when test="${not empty footer.anchor}">href="${footer.url}.${footer.Selector}.html"</c:when>
       <c:otherwise>href="${footer.url}"</c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
    class="${footer.class}">
    <span>${footer.textHeader}</span>
    </a>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise><span>${footer.defaultText}</span></c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

I'm a newb to JSTL so code samples were applicable would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I suggest using a custom tag (like footer.tag) to add a footer (presumably there will be footers on many pages). This way at least the code is centralized in one location only.

If a custom tag fills up with code, consider coding it in Java: I would say building a link is already a candidate for writing it in a Java class, because of many optional arguments.

Generally speaking, if you end up with too many c:choose et. al., you could possibly improve your *model* (in your case: FooterComponent). So if its possible to simplify the logic in the view, I would add more functionality to the model, and just call the methods in the view. So the if/switch statements remain in the model, and they do not clutter up your view.